# How do I loop through workbooks performing the same function in each?

Tags: vba, excel

I've been trying to create a macro that extracts specific cell data  from several open workbooks that all contain a specific sheet named ("Report_Final")

Currently, my macro goes sth like this:

```
Sub PerLineItem()
'Main function i'm trying to call for each open workbook

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim i, j, k, x, rng As Integer
Dim temp_total As Double
Dim mat_name1, mat_name2 As String

i = 2
j = 2
k = 2
rng = 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Sheets.Add
Set ws = ActiveSheet
'Intermediate sheet to filter only columns 2, 11 & 18'
ws.Name = "Report"
Cells(1, 2) = "WBS"
Cells(1, 3) = "Material"
Cells(1, 4) = "Sell Total Price"
Sheets("zero250").Select

Do While Cells(i, 2) <> ""
    rng = rng + 1
    i = i + 1
Loop
'Copy and paste columns 2, 11, 18 to 2, 3, 4 in the new sheet("Report")
Do While j < rng
   If ((Right(Cells(j, 2), 3) = "RTN") Or (Right(Cells(j, 2), 3) = "NRT")) Then

        Union(Cells(j, 2), Cells(j, 11), Cells(j, 18)).Copy
        Sheets("Report").Select
        Union(Cells(k, 2), Cells(k, 3), Cells(k, 3)).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

        Sheets("zero250").Select
        k = k + 1
        End If
    j = j + 1
Loop
'Create new sheet to group up identical named materials and sum the value up
Sheets.Add
Set ws2 = ActiveSheet
'The debugger always points to the below line "name is already taken" since it is being run in the same workbook
ws2.Name = "Report_Final"

Sheets("Report").Select
i = 2
j = 2
k = 2
x = 2
rng = 1

Do While Cells(i, 2) <> ""
    rng = rng + 1
    i = i + 1

Loop
'deletes identicals names and sums the value up, puts the values onto sheet("Report_final")
Do While j <= rng
    If Cells(j, 3) <> "" Then
        mat_name1 = Cells(j, 3).Value
        temp_total = Cells(j, 4).Value
        For x = j To rng
            mat_name2 = Cells(x + 1, 3).Value

            If mat_name2 = mat_name1 Then
            temp_total = temp_total + Cells(x + 1, 4).Value
            Rows(x + 1).ClearContents
            End If
        Next x

        Sheets("Report_Final").Select
        Cells(k, 2) = mat_name1
        Cells(k, 3) = temp_total
        Sheets("Report").Select
        Rows(j).ClearContents

        k = k + 1
        j = j + 1

    Else

        j = j + 1
    End If
Loop
'Labels the new columns in "Report_Final" and calculates the grand total
ws2.Select
Cells(1, 1).Value = wb.Name
Cells(1, 2).Value = "Material"
Cells(1, 3).Value = "Sell Total Price"
Cells(k, 3).Value = Application.Sum(Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(k, 3)))
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'Deletes intermediate sheet "Report"
Sheets("Report").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

In my Main function where I use:

```
For each wb in Workbooks

    PerLineItem

Next wb
```

It doesn't call PerLineItem for each of the open workbooks but instead trys to perform the function again on the same workbook.

P.S I know there may be a easier way to write all this code but I do not know prior knowledge to VBA :(

Edit : Hi so I've used your code with a little modification and it works fine! But now when i add this next part, it only works through the last workbook, as the counter k does not seem to loop for the earlier workbooks

```
'~~> cleaning up the sheet still goes here

With wb.Sheets("Report")
    rng2 = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    MsgBox rng2
        Do While j <= rng2
            If Cells(j, 3) <> "" Then
                mat_name1 = .Cells(j, 3).Value
                temp_total = .Cells(j, 4).Value
                For x = j To rng2
                    mat_name2 = .Cells(x + 1, 3).Value
                    If mat_name2 = mat_name1 Then
                        temp_total = temp_total + .Cells(x + 1, 4).Value
                        .Rows(x + 1).ClearContents
                    End If
                Next x

                .Rows(j).ClearContents
                .Cells(k, 2) = mat_name1
                .Cells(k, 3) = temp_total

                k = k + 1
                j = j + 1
            Else
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Loop
        MsgBox k
End With
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
End With
```

P.S I've decided to scrap creating another worksheet and work within "Report"

Comment: So how did it turn out? :) Yep. That's exactly what I was planning to do, to just work on Report. If your just summarizing what's on Report, wouldn't a pivot table work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim wb As Workbook

For Each wb in Workbooks
    If wb.Name <> Thisworkbook.Name Then
        PerLineItem wb
    End If
Next
```

**Edit1:** You need to adapt your sub like this

```
Private Sub PerLineItem(wb As Workbook)
Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, x As Long, rng As Long
Dim temp_total As Double
Dim mat_name1 As string, mat_name2 As String

i = 2: j = 2: k = 2: rng = 0

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With
'~~> Improve initializing ws
Set ws = wb.Sheets.Add(wb.Sheets(1))
ws.Name = "Report"
'~~> Directly work on your object; You can also use the commented lines
With ws
    .Cells(1, 2) = "WBS" '.Range("B1") = "WBS"
    .Cells(1, 3) = "Material" '.Range("C1") = "Material"
    .Cells(1, 4) = "Sell Total Price" '.Range("D1") = "Sell Total Price"
End With
'~~> Same with the other worksheet
With wb.Sheets("zero250")
    rng = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Range("B1:B" & rng).AutoFilter 1, "=*RTN*", xlOr, "=*NRT*"
    .Range("B1:B" & rng).Offset(1,0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisisble).Copy _
        ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlup).Offset(1,0)
End With
'~~> cleaning up the sheet still goes here
End Sub
```

Above code is the equivalent of your code up to generating the *Report* Sheet only.
Can you continue? :) I run out of time. ;p
Btw, hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! I've tried your code and it keeps returning the error 'Method or Data not found' highlighting the wb.Name part

Comment: can you edit your question and post your code? It works fine on my end.